# Details of AWS secure token service protocol

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

AWS authenticates accesses to its various API endpoints using a protocol consisting (on the client side) of  user id, user secret and volatile session token. This protocol is lightweight and easy to use (as compared to SAML or GSSAPI based authentication), so I would like to use a similar approach with some web services not directly connected to AWS.

So the questions are:

1. Had Amazon published regarding the details of its secure token protocol somewhere?
2. Are there any implementations (desirably open source) of similarly simple and lightweight claim based authentication protocols? In particular, I'm interested in implementations that do not require complex external dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The presently used AWS authentication mechanism is called SigV4 and is documented in some details here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html

There exist several "stand alone" (not bundled with the rest of AWS api) libraries to handle SigV4 tokens on github.